# Fatal error in Kunena Component v. 3.0.4

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

i just installed the kunena component (latest version) in my joomla v3.2.1 website.
When i am trying to reach the component from backend i am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'KunenaForum' not found in
>   /mysitename/administrator/components/com_kunena/install/model.php on
>   line 1345

Mysql server version is 5.5

I am searching for 5 days to find a solution but nothing.

Can anyone help?

Comment: This is basically a miss location of the component problem. You are trying to access a component which is not where it should be! You have to check on this Kunema Component if it has some configuration file to you change the paths properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved! If anyone gets the same error, you have to disable system cache during the installation of the kunena component.